# (class) does not name a type error in c++

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors, include

Please note that I have looked at other questions on stack overflow before posting this question. I have not found any solutions that worked.

(This is simplified) 
I have five files: 
`assets.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

#include <map>
#include <string>

// Asset Manager class
class AssetManager {
    private:
       std::map<std::string, SDL_Texture*> textures;

   public:
      AssetManager();
      ~AssetManager();

      void addTexture(std::string id, const char *path);
      
      SDL_Texture *getTexture(std::string id);
};
```

`assets.cpp`

```cpp
#include "assets.h"

// Constructor
AssetManager::AssetManager() {}

// Destructor
AssetManager::~AssetManager() {
    // Destructor code
}

// Adds texture to "textures"
void AssetManager::addTexture(std::string id, const char *path) {
    // Code for adding texture
}

// Gets texture from "textures"
SDL_Texture *AssetManager::getTexture(std::string id) {
    // Code for getting texture
}
```

`game.h`

```
#pragma once

class AssetManager; // assets.h include in game.cpp (see below)

class Game {
    private:
        // Code here

    public:
        static AssetManager *assets;
        // More code here
};
```

`game.cpp`

```cpp
#include "assets.h"
#include "game.h"

AssetManager *Game::assets = new AssetManager();

// Code for game here
```

`other_file.cpp`

```cpp
#include "game.h"

Game::assets->getTexture[<id>] // <-- This is where the error comes from
```

Even though I used a forward decleration of class "AssetsManager" in `game.h`, and then included `assets.h` in `game.cpp`, when included from other files it gives this error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class AssetManager'
```

Why does it say "AssetManager" is an incomplete type?

Comment: A class type is incomplete until the end of its definition. A forward-declaration declares the type, but does not make it complete. A forward declaration is not a definition. Nothing you are showing in your question requires `AssetManager` to be complete though. The issue is in the line that the error message refers to which you are not showing.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, and add a comment on the line where you get the error.

Comment: The program [works here](https://onlinegdb.com/szPg6u3pc)

Comment: Okay I'll see what I can do to improve the question

Comment: In other_file.cpp add `#include "assets.h"`

Comment: Or just `#include "assets.h"` in `game.h` instead of the forward declaration? The `assets.h` header doesn't include anything that could lead to circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a `#include` statement in `other_file.cpp`.